# Most efficient way of downloading and parsing XML

Tags: xml, linux, performance, parsing

I'm looking to regularly download XML files from remote locations, analyse and store the results in a database. It will be running on my dedicated Linux server, however, I am not sure which is the most efficient way of doing this is as I'm not sure of the overheads of different languages.

I have looked at some options and I could either download and analyse them completely in PHP, Perl, Python or C, or use a combination (one to download with little overheads, one to analyse, one to store in database). What would be the best option / combination?

Cheers for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a (very) general rule of thumb, C will have the least overhead and will be fastest. (Because it's compiled, not interpreted.)

That being said, that difference generally isn't noticeable. Unless you're dealing with seriously massive XML documents, you're talking milliseconds. The design of the XML library you choose to use, not the language, will have a far larger impact.

I think this is a case of premature optimization. Do you know in advance that your XML files are huge? Pick the language you like. If you do run into trouble, *then* you can export the bottleneck into another language.

My guess is the bottleneck will be your network connection, not parsing/analyzing/storing.

Comment: I did have a feeling that this premature optimisation could cause a lot of hassle. I have been looking at RSS_PHP [link](http://rssphp.net/) as it seems the most robust and keeps all information. (There is a combination of XML and RSS documents being downloaded).

Comment: @jonnyweb, that'll work just fine. I would caution you against PHP, though — since it's designed to run behind a web server, it's a bit more complicated to get it to run on a standalone Linux box.

Comment: If PHP is what you're comfortable with, though, then go for it!

Comment: I have PHP running in a LAMP environment, I figure that I will just run the script via a cronjob (as I do this currently for other scheduled tasks). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Python is quite easy to use: the package xml.dom.minidom makes a lot of things really simple.